# How to check a function pointer exists

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, function-pointers

In C++, I'm trying to write a function with function pointers. I want to be able to throw an exception if a function pointer is passed for a function that does not exist. I tried to handle the function pointer like a normal pointer and check if it is null

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int add_1(const int& x) {
    return x + 1;
}

int foo(const int& x, int (*funcPtr)(const int& x)) {
    if (funcPtr != NULL) {
        return funcPtr(x);
    } else {
        throw "not a valid function pointer";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
try {
    int x = 5;

    cout << "add_1 result is " << add_1(x) << endl;

    cout << "foo add_1 result is " << foo(x, add_1) << endl;
    cout << "foo add_2 result is " << foo(x, add_2) << endl; //should produce an error
}
catch (const char* strException) {
    cerr << "Error: " << strException << endl;
}
catch (...) {
    cerr << "We caught an exception of an undetermined type" << endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the calling code?

Comment: Did you at least test it by passing `NULL` or `nullptr` as the argument for the function pointer?

Comment: @RSahu I have added more code for how it might be used.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I'm more concerned about passing a function that doesn't exist than passing a null pointer. I was just trying to figure out how to go about doing that.

Comment: @John, the line with `add_2` will result in a compiler error if it is not declared and a link time error if it is declared and not defined.

Comment: @RSahu I'm getting the sense that there's no way around that, but I want to make sure.

Comment: If a function is referenced and it is declared but not defined the link stage will fail. You don't have to worry about the function no existing.

Comment: In case you actually care about the answers to your question, the one you selected is wrong, or at the very least quite misleading.

Comment: @juanchopanza I had accepted it because basically everyone was saying the same thing. If you think it is misleading and wrong, then provide an answer that is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking for NULL is ok. But it is not possible to pass a pointer to a function that does not exist in the  first place. So you don't have to worry about this. Although it is possible to just declare a function without defining it and pass the address of it. In that case you will get linker error.

Comment: Why is it not possible to pass a pointer to a function that does not exist?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well, you could use something like `memcpy()` to copy garbage into a function pointer object. Other than that, there's no way to construct a function pointer value (other than the null pointer) that doesn't point to an actual function.

Comment: @KeithThompson Couldn't you just pass an uninitialized function pointer?

Comment: So, in conclusion, the second and third sentences of this answer are wrong.

Comment: @KeithThompson: or just cast an arbitrary integer into the function pointer type

Comment: @juanchopanza, 2nd line means "It is not possible to take address of a function and pass as argument that does not exist." Passing uninitialized pointer is same as casting int to pointer and pass it. You can think it as a pointer to a function that does not exist, but here comes my 3rd line: you don't have to worry about it, because NO CHECK can prevent users of the function doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically throw an error if you are passing pointer which does not exist, if you are declaring a pointer then you have to initialize it with null to avoid garbage value, so comparing with null will not serve any purpose.

you still you want to check then try to assign some function(like add, sub etc.), if it takes then ok , if not then it will show again error as previously mentioned.

Comment: "It will automatically throw an error if you are passing pointer which does not exist" The standard does not say anything about "throwing an error". It is undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<cstddef>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int foo(const int& x, int (*funcPtr)(const int& x)) {
    if (*funcPtr != NULL) {
        return funcPtr(x);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not a valid function pointer";
    }
}
```

If you want to 'throw' exception then you need to 'catch' it as well.
Your code is failing because of two reasons in short,
1) You are not checking value of function pointer.
2) You are not properly catching the thrown exception.